# Question blanks out if edited while looking at vote to close dialog

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, live-refresh, firefox

I've had several occasions now where I'm looking for a duplicate of a question.  While I'm searching through the results looking for an appropriate duplicate, the question is edited (I get the "question was edited" banner at the top).

If I then click on the "back to search results" of the floating "duplicate" dialog (to get back to the list of questions), the question refreshes and the "duplicate" dialog goes away, but the entire question area is blank. The vote up/down arrows, comments, and existing answers still show. If I Ctrl-A to select all the content of the page, nothing in the question area highlights. However, the question is still there as the mouse cursor responds to content I cannot see (changes between arrow and edit bar, for example), and if I click and drag the question area I get a drag image that shows the question.

At some point my twiddling with dragging caused the question to refresh and to appear without having to explicitly refresh the page.

[image: image of hidden question]

This is when running Firefox on Windows 10.

Comment: Are you certain that it *entirely* blanks out, rather than being replaced by a small little banner at the very top that says something like, "click here to show latest changes"? I haven't seen this personally, but it does require ideal circumstances to repro.

Comment: @CodyGray I see the banner when I still have the close dialog up.  When I click off the dialog to dismiss it (without selecting a duplicate), the whole question area blanks out.

Comment: I'll add more details as I discover what the sequence is to reproduce this.

Comment: This just happened to me. After going through the close-vote dialog, typing in the duplicate target link, and pressing “Vote to Close”, the question did this “edit flash”, but remained in the blank state. The DOM of the question was fully available, but it was fully transparent.

Comment: Cross-site post on MSE: [When VTCing as dupe, if the question you're on gets edited before you VTC, the whole question goes blank](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348173/289905).